# Associative array inside array in PHP

Tags: php, associative-array

After fetching a result from the database, and preparing the array for the JSON enconde, I face a dilemma on how to reference the array 'data' inside the main array.

The "[0]" by far is an error of my logic...

```
while ($row =$result->fetch()) {
    $name     = $row['country'];
    $id       = $row['id']
    $username = $row['username'];
    $subtotal = $row['subtotal'];

    if ( /* If $id exist in array row['series']}*/ ) {

        ///?????/////
        /// Add array to 'DATA'
        ////?????////

        $rows['series']["$id"]["$name"]['data'][]=array("$username", $subtotal);
    }
    else {
        $rows['series'][]= array('id' => "$id", 'name' => "$name", 'data' => array("$username", $subtotal));
    }
```

The vardump show as follow:

```
array(1) {
  ["series"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(7) "hn"
      ["name"]=>
      string(8) "HN"
      ["data"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(17) "GK_5"
        [1]=>
        string(5) "86040"
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(7) "hn"
      ["name"]=>
      string(8) "HN"
      ["data"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(17) "GK_8"
        [1]=>
        string(5) "20358"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I want to add the last item with same id/name like this:

```
array(1) {
  ["series"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(7) "hn"
      ["name"]=>
      string(8) "HN"
      ["data"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(17) "GK_5"
        [1]=>
        string(5) "86040"
      }
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(17) "GK_8"
        [1]=>
        string(5) "20358"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: my head.... Stop using mysql_ functions. See the big red box: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: `if (isset($rows)&&(strcmp($id,$rows['series'][0]['id']))&& (strcmp($name,$rows['series'][0]['name']))){
               echo "yes";     
            }else{              
               echo "no";            }` --- it is yes or no? try it please

Comment: See how bad just invites bad over for dinner?

Comment: thanks Rottingham/Pavel  for your comments I just edit my question taking out some unnecessary code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most natural way would be to change your data structure a bit, so that the `series` array is indexed by the row ID instead of an arbitrary running index.  The would allow you to rewrite your loop to (using [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) syntax as an example):

```
$stmt->bind_result($id, $country, $username, $subtotal);

$series = array();
while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
     $series[$id]['country'] = $country;
     $series[$id]['data'][] = array(
         'username' => $username,
         'subtotal' => $subtotal,
     );
}
```

which [will give you](http://ideone.com/3Vu9mL) a data structure like:

```
$series = array(
    'hn' => array(
        'country' => 'HN',
        'data' => array(
            0 => array(
                'username' => 'GK_5',
                'subtotal' => 86040
            ),
            1 => array(
                'username' => 'GK_8',
                'subtotal' => 20358
            ),
            // ...
        )
    ),
    // ...
);
```

If you *need* the data in the exact format shown in your post, you can of course loop over this array with `foreach` to transform it, e.g.:

```
$rows = array();
foreach ( $series as $id => $record ) {
    $record['id'] = $id;
    $rows['series'][] = $record;
}
```

Comment: it's is so obvious my if was for another graph that summarize by stripping last 2 chars in the username....thanks a lot. @Karonen